# Compiler alert/warning for versions higher than Java 8

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I am building applications using OpenJDK11, Maven.
As my application will be used by clients who are using Java 8 and still not migrated to Java 11,
I need to know is there a way I can get alerts at compile time if my application is using higher version of Java 8.

Comment: Not sure it can be what you may want but you might give it a try to `maven-enforcer-plugin` but it will work when you are building with maven. More specifically its rule `requireJavaVersion`

Comment: The maven-enforcer-plugin is the correct way. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/ and https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html

Comment: NeoChiri khmarbaise Thank you for suggestion. 
Since I have java 11 already in my system I guess this is not working

     <configuration>
      <rules>
       <requireJavaVersion>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <message>Invalid Java version. It should, at least, be 1.8</message>
       </requireJavaVersion>
      </rules>
     </configuration>